# Docusign API: I want to attach some PDF to the envelope as appendix. Which API do I use?

Tags: python, docusignapi

I need to upload some file-like objects to docusign as appendix. There's no action needed to be done by any signer. They are just there as some additional info.

I found [this](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/updateList) which details creating one or more documents to an envelope, but at the same time I found [this](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeAttachments/create) which also creates attachment. I don't know which one is the one I need. In addition, there's also [this](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocumentTabs/createDocumentTabs#TemplateRecipientTabs) which adds more complexity to this issue.

DocuSign has listed both in [here](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/documents) , which is even more confusing

I'm simply using python's `requests` library to make the call, but I don't know which one is the correct one to make.

Comment: envelope API Attachment referred in [your document](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/v2/reference/envelopes/envelopeattachments/create) is used to add some extra documents on an envelope via API only and these attachments will never be visible to the envelope's recipients. These API attachments will be like metadata documents in the envelope. If you want to show the documents to the recipients, then just add them as normal document base64 or binary on an envelope and do not add any tabs on those documents. Then these documents will be visible to all recipients.

Comment: By adding documents are inline, those documents will be shown on the signing screen to each signers and they can scroll over it by using the side scrollbar. There is `Supplemental Docs`, Supplemental docs are supporting materials, such as disclosures and other informational documents that recipients may view and acknowledge, but that don't need to be signed. So they will be part of the envelope, button recipients need to click a button (if they want) to see these documents else no action is needed by them.

Comment: So it is you or your business team call to use Supplemental Docs (open as a modal on a click of a button) or use documents are inline. Supplemental Docs are not available in all DS Plans so you might need to check with your DS Acct Manager to know if Supplemental Docs is included in your subscription plan or not.

Comment: @AmitKBist This is good. Thanks for the explanation. I'll mark your comment as answer. Currently I'm planning to attach them as normal document. It does the job. We don't foresee any issue since these docs are small in number and size. Though I did mention it to the team to get a second opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it seems like the "appendix" is just a document. You won't have any tabs (signing indicators) in that document, but it's still a document.
You can either use the PUT API to add a new document, or if you already creating the envelope using the API, the initial POST can be used to add all the documents you need.
Use this API call for updating a document

```
PUT /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents
```

Comment: both first and second links are for PUT though. which one is the correct one to use?

Comment: first one, let me clarify the answer

Comment: may I ask one more question: how many fields in `envelopeDefinition` are required? What's the minimum I need to successfully upload a file?

Comment: I'm a little confused, uploading a file doesn't require envelopeDefinition unless you are doing that while also creating an envelope.  Are you making a single API call to create an envelope? is this different than what you originally was asking about?

Comment: No, the envelope is already created. All I need to do is adding one or more files as appendix (again, no action needed to be done by any signer) to such envelope

Comment: it's in the API doc. Unless I got it wrong. What's the correct fields to use?

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/update look here
all you need is your accountId, envelopeId and documentId
and then just the body which includes the name and the document itself

Comment: I think ```name, fileExtension , documentId , and documentBase64 ```
is what I need.

Comment: yup, you got it. anything else I can help you with?